# when using NSUInteger in a decreasing for loop, how to determine >= 0

Tags: objective-c

If I want to use a loop like

```
for (NSUInteger row = 10; row >= 0; row--) {
  // do something
}
```

how do I get around the fact that row will always be > 0 since it's an unsigned integer.  Does the middle construct of the for loop just become:

```
for (NSUInteger row = 10; row; row--) {

}
```

Comment: By definition these indices shouldn't be negative, so using NSUInteger communicates semantic intent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use NSInteger instead of NSUInteger this gets a bit simpler. Because NSInteger is a signed integer type, calling the decrement operator (`--`) on a variable with the value zero changes the value to -1, so you can test for this using a simple comparison:

```
for (NSInteger row = 10; row >= 0; row--) {
    // do stuff with row
}
```

If you have to use an NSUInteger for some reason then calling the decrement operator on a variable with a value of zero will result in the variable's value wrapping around to the maximum possible value for NSUInteger. You can test for this using `NSUIntegerMax`.

```
for (NSUInteger row = 10; row != NSUIntegerMax; row--) {
    // do stuff with row
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need an unsigned? If so, you'll have to come up with a test that does what you want. Possibly row>=0 && row<=10, although that's a bit clunky for my tastes.

Edit: Just wanted to add that the comparison of unsigned >=0 is superfluous, but if you are going to stick with unsigned, I would leave it, because it at least conveys intent.

Comment: "I would leave it, because it at least conveys intent." It also yields a compiler warning, so should be removed. (If you leave your code littered with constructs that generate "ignorable" compiler warnings it makes you less likely to spot new, potentially more important warnings when they appear.)

Comment: Well, if we are really talking about what I *would* do, I wouldn't use this construct to begin with. If I were constrained to use an unsigned here, I would still specify the range explicitly rather than rely on non-idomatic constructs like comparing to `NSUIntegerMax`. I don't agree that all code resulting in a warning needs to be changed--if that were the case, they might as well be errors.

Answer (score 0):

You should either do this:

```
for (NSUInteger row = 10; row >= 1; row--) {
}
```

or this:

```
for (NSInteger row = 10; row >= 0; row--) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (NSUInteger index = 11; index > 0; index--) {
  NSUInteger row = index-1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use a NSUInteger

```
for (NSUInteger row = 10; row >= 0; row--) {
     // do something
    if(row == 0) {break;}
}
```

Otherwise, try using a NSInteger as Simon Whitaker suggested

Answer (score 0):

Another trick is to move decrement to condition check part. By the way this loop one operation less that classic one.

```
for (NSUInteger i = 10; i-- > 0;)
{
}
```